# boost python import error on mac snow leopard macports

Tags: python, c++, macos, boost

On snow leopard (OS X 10.6.8), I have trouble loading the extension module built using boost python. The code is:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
char const* greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(func_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

I built using:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -o src/func_ext.os -c -fPIC -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/opt/local/include src/func_ext.cpp
/usr/bin/g++ -o func_ext.dylib -dynamiclib src/func_ext.os -L/opt/local/lib -lpython2.7 -lboost_python-mt
```

The error is:

```
15:52:53@tscons=>LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd` python
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import func_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ImportError: No module named func_ext
```

Can anyone please help?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The most immediate issue, I think, is that you should use `.so` instead of `.dylib` for the extension module file name.

If that doesn't fix everything, you might use the `python-config` command to make sure you're using all of the right compiler and linker settings.